# How to split string between commas and store each in an array variable using vba

Tags: arrays, string, vba, excel

**I have a question:** 
  How can I split the string between commas which are inside open and closed parentheses and store each in an array variable?

**Example:**

```
strinput = "( u1 u1t_a, u2 u2t_b, s2 s2t_c, s4 s4t_d, ...n )"
```

Having an input string above, I want to store in an array variable the three and so on substring between commas which are inside open and closed parentheses :

```
substr(0) = "u1 u1t_a"
substr(1) = "u2 u2t_b"
substr(2) = "s2 s2t_c"
substr(n) = "...n"
```

As of now, I am having difficulty of using loop together with array in VBA so my code is like a brute force which can only process a maximum of 3 text since the code will became long so I made a limit.

*See my code here:*

```
strinput = "( u1 u1t_a, u2 u2t_b, s2 s2t_c )"

substr1 = Right(strinput, Len(strinput) - Find("(", strinput))
    'Output: u1 u1t_a, u2 u2t_b, s2 s2t_c )
substr1f = Left(substr1, Find(",", substr1) - 1)
    'Output: u1 u1t_a

substr2 = Right(substr1, Len(substr1) - Find("(", substr1))
    'Output: u2 u2t_b, s2 s2t_c )
substr2f = Left(substr2, Find(",", substr2) - 1)
    'Output: u2 u2t_b

substr3 = Right(substr2, Len(substr2) - Find("(", substr2))
    'Output: s2 s2t_c )
substr3f = Left(substr3, Find(")", substr3) - 1)
    'Output: s2 s2t_c
```

How can I make this loop?

Comment: Start with counting the number of commas in your string. Then make a loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ar As Variant
    Dim strinput  As String, s As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    strinput = "( u1 u1t_a, u2 u2t_b, s2 s2t_c, s4 s4t_d, ...n )"
    
    '~~> Replace ( and ) with ""
    s = Replace(Replace(strinput, ")", ""), "(", "")
    
    '~~> Split and store in an arry based on ","
    Ar = Split(s, ",")
    
    '~~> See what is there in the array
    For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
        Debug.Print Ar(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you want to combine the `Replace and Split` then you can use this as well

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ar As Variant
    Dim strinput  As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    strinput = "( u1 u1t_a, u2 u2t_b, s2 s2t_c, s4 s4t_d, ...n )"
            
    Ar = Split(Split(Split(strinput, "(")(1), ")")(0), ",")
    
    '~~> See what is there in the array
    For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
        Debug.Print Ar(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Rout for your response, I tried the code and it works just like what I've wanted. Also because of your answer, I just realize the idea of having to replace first the open and closed parentheses, then focus on string between commas, that's an awesome technique and problem solving I just learned. For now, I will learn the functions of LBound and UBoundin the code.

Also, thank you for providing comments so that I can understand your code, I really appreciate it!

Having my first question, with this welcoming answer really makes me feel welcomed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
Sub qwerty()

    strinput = "( u1 u1t_a, u2 u2t_b, s2 s2t_c, s4 s4t_d, ...n )"
    strinput = Replace(Replace(strinput, "( ", ""), " )", "")
    arr = Split(strinput, ", ")

    For Each a In arr
        MsgBox a
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I tried this and it works. But I have additional question, I don't understand the variable a, how does it able to output the correct string? Like how does variable a works together with variable arr in loop? Thank you very much!

Comment: @VinIsLearning  the variable ***a*** represents an **individual item** in the array `arr()`

Answer (score 0):

Another flavour:

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim strinput As String, a As Variant
    strinput = "( u1 u1t_a, u2 u2t_b, s2 s2t_c, s4 s4t_d, ...n )"
    For Each a In Split(Mid$(strinput, 3, Len(strinput) - 4), ", ") ‘ first extract a substring out of your string leaving off first two and last two characters, then Split resulting string using commas as delimiter
        MsgBox a
    Next
End Sub
```

You can [see here for Mid$() function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mid.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trim function to remove blank spaces.

```
Sub test()
    Dim substr As Variant
    Dim strinput As String
    Dim i As Long

    strinput = "( u1 u1t_a, u2 u2t_b, s2 s2t_c, s4 s4t_d, ...n )"

    strinput = Replace(strinput, "(", "")
    strinput = Replace(strinput, ")", "")

    substr = Split(strinput, ",")

    For i = LBound(substr) To UBound(substr)
        substr(i) = Trim(substr(i))
        Debug.Print substr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```